# Spring Boot Remember Me Token into H2 DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, token

I am trying to create Spring Boot Application that uses Remember Me Token that is saved into H2 DB.
Token gets saved but when I delete JSSESSIONID and remember-me Cookies and then I try to call http://localhost:8080/Hello again I need to Log in again instead of using Remember Me Token from the DB (if I properly assume what to expect). And another Token is saved with the same Username.

application.properties

```
# SECURITY
spring.security.user.name             = myuser
spring.security.user.password         = mypassword
spring.security.user.roles            = USER

# H2 DATABASE
spring.h2.console.enabled             = true
spring.datasource.url                 = jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.initialization-mode = always
```

schema.sql

```
create table persistent_logins (
  username  varchar(64) not null,
  series    varchar(64) primary key,
  token     varchar(64) not null,
  last_used timestamp   not null
);
```

MyController.java

```
package com.ivoronline.springboot_security_rememberme_db_h2.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

  //=================================================================
  // HELLO
  //=================================================================
  @RequestMapping("Hello")
  String hello() {
    return "Hello from Controller";
  }
  
}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package com.ivoronline.springboot_security_rememberme_db_h2.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenRepository;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  //PROPERTIES
  @Autowired UserDetailsService        userDetailsService;
  @Autowired PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;

  //=================================================================
  // PERSISTENT TOKEN REPOSITORY
  //=================================================================
  @Bean
  public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
                            tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
  }

  //=================================================================
  // CONFIGURE
  //=================================================================
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    //ENABLE REMEMBER ME COOKIE
    httpSecurity.rememberMe()
      .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository)
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

    //H2 CONSOLE
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(authorize -> { authorize.antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll(); });
    httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    //DISABLE CSRF
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

    //SECURE ALL RESOURCES
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

    //DEFAULT LOGIN FORM
    httpSecurity.formLogin();

  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `rememberMe` is not being activated for any of endpoints.
In that case, can you try something like this:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository).userDetailService(userDetailsService).and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize.antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
                }).headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I guess I misunderstood how this works.
So in both cases there should be Browser's Cookie but with different information.

With Browser based Remember-me Cookie contains Base64 encoded
myuser:1648219725190:7e829e8197008d754a39c9df4c3b5386

With DB based Remember-me Cookie contains Base64 encoded
series and token that are stored into DB

https://www.base64decode.org/